# jQuery Window Load not firing when called from within function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery the following would log that the app had loaded once the DOM and all assets had been downloaded by the browser:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    console.log('app loaded');

});
```

However I don't want this check to happen until after some other things have run.

So for example:

```
function checkLoaded()
{           
    $(window).load(function() {

        console.log('app loaded');

    });
}
```

So let's say I call this function after a bunch of other functions.

The problem is, because `$(window).load(function()` is an event listener, when I call the `checkLoaded()` function the event won't ALWAYS run (because it MAY have already been fired because everything has downloaded BEFORE the `checkLoaded()` function has run).

Any ideas on how I can do this?

I tried this:

```
function checkLoaded()
{           
    if(loaded)
    {
        console.log('app loaded');
    }
    else
    {
        checkLoaded(); // keep checking until the loaded becomes true
    }
}

$(window).load(function(){

    loaded = true;

});
```

But the problem here is that the checkLoaded function COULD get called hundreds of times in a few seconds and isn't a nice way of handling this.

**UPDATE: The function is called using checkLoaded(); Just so everyone knows I am calling the function!**

**UPDATE 2:**

The plan is essentially this:

```
function init() {

    start();

}();

function start() {

    // Show Preloader... and other stuff

    /// Once all logic has finished call checkLoaded

    checkLoaded();

}

function checkLoaded() {

    if(loaded) {

        show();

    }

}

function show() {

    ... // show app

}
```

So I should be able to know if the status of loaded is true, but keep checking until it becomes true as it may be true or false when I get to the checking stage.

Comment: What are "the other things" ?

Comment: So why do you need to wrap it inside window onload?

Comment: How else would I know that the browser has downloaded all assets? Like I said it won't ALWAYS happen, but sometimes the download BEFORE the function gets called.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem, so why are you wrapping window onload event inside checkLoaded() function? Could you provide a more concrete sample of your issue?

Comment: in your edit code, using a timeout to recall function would work BUT why would you need that? Ok, i think i misunderstood "assets" terms, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run it either on window load or if it's already done using such kind of code:

```
function onLoad(loading, loaded) {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        return loaded();
    } 
    loading();

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', loaded);
    }
}

onLoad(function() {
    console.log('I am waiting for the page to be loaded');
}, function() {
    console.log('The page is loaded');
});
```

Comment: So I'd just call onLoad AFTER all my other code to check the status? Or would it be called immediately and cb would do the check?

Comment: We could use it to replace `$(window).onload(cb)` were you want

Comment: Could you show a full example of how you'd imagine this working based on the flow I posted above (last chunk of code in OP). As I don't fully understand how I'd use this. Thanks.

Comment: Will that call loaded multiple times until it has? Or ONLY once it has loaded.. if the latter then awesome. Otherwise it will suffer the performance issues in my original. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var loaded=false;
$(window).load(function() {
    loaded=true;
});
function checkLoaded()
{
     // do something if loaded===true 
}
```

Comment: What if checkLoaded gets called before window load sets the loaded value to true? I'd then need a way to keep checking until this value becomes true.

Comment: you want to make checkLoaded block and thats a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function checkLoaded()
{           
    $(window).load(function() {

        console.log('app loaded');

    });
}
checkLoaded();
```

Comment: I know how to call a function!

Comment: but this isn't what you have so why the hostility?

Comment: I'd of thought it was obvious I was calling the function and not just expecting it to be called automatically unless I did `function checkLoaded() { ... }();`

Answer (score 0):

you want to make checkLoaded block and thats a bad idea:

javascript has no threads and blocking like that will just burn CPU while potentially blocking the whole script.

don't wait like you do for loaded to be to true. use the eventhandler as it is meant to be used.

maybe give checkLoaded a parameter to a function you want called:

```
function checkLoaded(continueWhenLoaded) {
     $(window).load(function() {
         continueWhenLoaded();
     });
}
```

Comment: What is that parameter `continueWhenLoaded` in the checkLoaded function?

Comment: Is it the actual function that I want called?

Comment: the continuation... so when A would call checkLoaded before, you split A into A>sub function1 and A>subfunction2. subfunction1 would call checkLoaded at its end end pass it subfunction2

Comment: Sorry pal that's gone over my head a bit. Could you flesh out your answer a bit to explain your comment. Thanks.

Comment: Ill try sorry.. give me some time

Comment: Take a look at my edited post to see the flow I'm trying to achieve. Basically I want to know if everything has loaded but only care once I ask for the status BUT the status could be true or false at this point of check, so I need to keep checking UNTIL it becomes true.

Comment: you already accepted an answer that does exactly what I told you.

Comment: Yeah he edited it an hour ago. Is his answer what you were thinking?

Comment: yes it isn't 100% what I wanted to do but it is the same thought. looks ok

Comment: Yeah it works great, it'd still be interesting to see your idea if you have time? Might be a better solution / helpful to others? Thanks for your input so far.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into a solution involving jQuery's [.promise()](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) and [.done()](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)? Look at some of the examples in the documentation, it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps, although I'm not seeing it at the moment.